# What is the correct way to open and close window/dialog?

Tags: qt, memory-management

I'm trying to develop a new program. The work flow looks like this:

```
Login --> Dashboard (Window with menus) --> Module 1
                                        --> Module 2
                                        --> Module 3
                                        --> Module XXX
```

So, to open Dashboard from Login (a Dialog), I use

```
Dashboard *d = new Dashboard();
d->show(); 
close();
```

In Dashboard, I use these codes to reopen the Login if the user closes the Window (by clicking the 'X')

```
closeEvent(QCloseEvent *) 
{
    Login *login = new Login();
    login->show();
}
```

With a Task Manager opened, I ran the program and monitor the memory usage. After clicking open Dashboard from Login and closing Dashboard to return to Login, I noticed that the memory keeps increasing about 500 KB. It can goes up to 20 MB from 12 MB of memory usage by just opening and closing the window/dialog.

So, what did I do wrong here ? I need to know it before I continue developing those modules which will definitely eat more memory with my programming. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason might be you are creating the `Login` widget again and again without **deleting** it.

I believe your **Login** is a `QWidget`, **Dashboard** is a `QDialog`. Instead of `close()`, just hide the **Login** widget by `hide()` or `setvisible(false)`.

In the `closeEvent()` of the **DashBoard** give 
`done(someIntValue);`

While accessing DashBoard, instead of show() give

```
int returnValue = d->exec();
```

if the `returnValue` is `someIntValue`, `show()` the Login Widget.

This way you are avoiding the creation of the **Login widget** multiple times. But a lot other factors might be responsible for your memory usage, which could be found out only by going through the entire code.

Edit:

Since your Dashboard is a QMainWindow you **can't** call `done(someIntValue);` Instead try connecting the `destroyed( QObject * obj = 0 )` signal of the **DashBoard** and in the corresponding slot `show()` your **Login**.. Of course you should have the **instance of the DashBoard** in the **Login** Dialog and the connection between the above signal and slot should be made in the **Login**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: **Login** is a QDialog and **Dashboard** is a QMainWindow


If I use `hide()` or `setVisible(false)`, I need to pass the variable from a class to class, right ? That's not very practical in my program since I might be calling other classes multiple times before clicking the close window button to return to **Login**


I know I should try avoiding the creation of any widget multiple times, but shouldn't there be no problem if I created something that has been destroyed, in this case, did my widget released its used memory when it has been closed ?

Comment: no i think you misunderstood. You don't have to pass objects here and there. you can hide the Login Dialog just by the call hide(), since you derived Login from a QDialog. To answer to your other question, the Dialog will be deleted only if you set the attribute manually for the Dialog as, Login->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

Comment: I think using `setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose)` works. But could you please give an example on how to reopen the **Login** dialog when I'm in **Dashboard** (without declaring new object) ? I can't just `show()` it back since there's no object associated with it. That's why I had to create a new object (which in result increases the memory usage)